# Exporting Images with my JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar

I am using Eclipse, and I wish to export some images in the "img" source folder along with my .jar, so they show up in the JAR.

My Heirarchy is :

> Project>src>Package>FILE.java

Then in project is another source folder called :

> img>IMAGE.png

I am currently linking to the images using :

```
lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/logo1.png"));
```

And that works fine, until I export it.

I am exporting it as an Runnable JAR file with `Extract required libraries` ticked, as the middle one will not allow the .jar to open. Extract allows it to open, but the images do not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path are not the same when you load data inside a JAR.

You can use this method to load image when you run from a JAR:

```
/**
  * Create an instance of ImageIcon with the given path
  * @param path  String - path of the image
  * @return  ImageIcon - ImageIcon made with the image at the given path
  */
private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    if (path != null) {
        URL tmp = getClass().getResource(path.replace("\\", "/"));
        if(tmp!=null)
            return new ImageIcon(tmp);
        else
            return new ImageIcon();
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that, then call it like so: lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(createImageIcon("logo1.png"));

It doesn't display the image

Comment: Ofc, the image is not in the same directory as your java file. If your "img" dir is at the same place as your "src" dir. I think you can try ../../img/logo1.png. I'm not 100% sure you know your file hierarchy better than me ;)

Comment: Nope. Nothing. It was fine showing the images in the program, except when I exported it, they werent showing anymore.

Comment: lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/logo1.png")); displays it just fine, but when I use it no longer shows. How do I export the images in the img folder so they will display in my runnable jar?

Comment: I use this method in jar so I'm sure it works. I don't know how you create your jar but obviously the path you gave is wrong. Open your jar and get the path to go from class file to the image file.

Comment: Reading the information below I'm sure the path img/logo1.png is wrong. You said that img folder is in project like src. To know your path just open the jar it's an archive like a rar... Then go in the directory were class files are stored. Then check the path to go in image dir from here. Use ../ when you go to parent dir (until project I think) then add the path to go to image file. if you don't know how to get path it's hard to help you...

Comment: It works fine when I use lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/logo1.png")); Yes, img is in the project folder, jsut like src.

Comment: So you tried with ../../img/logo1.png or even ../img/logo1.png maybe if previous one don't work...

Comment: Yes. I tried both of those. The following code displays the image perfectly. lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/logo1.png"));

Comment: In MANIFEST.MF my Class path is blank is that the problem?

Comment: As I said "img/logo1.png" is obviously not the right path. It implies that your img directory is at the same place as your java file. So I dont know why it works. It's probably cause of Eclipse so if you want to have a runnable jar don't test with eclipse but test using java -jar in a terminal. It's possible that it will work in the jar but not in Eclipse.

Comment: Fixed it :) Used your coded, but just moved the images into the src folder. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, maybe the easiest way ;) I check my app and often I do that to!