# export images with jar file using intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I've looked and tried several ways how to do this and I just can't seem to get it right. The program runs fine. After using intellij to export into a jar file (using this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xo6zSBgdgk), I get the following error when running the jar file...

[image]

These lines are as follows...

**line#44:**`setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(guiImgIconLocName)));` with String variable `guiImgIconLocName` = `"..\\images\\TitleBarIcon.png"`

and

**line#6134:**`new StartGui();` as part of the `public static void main(String[] args)` method

This is my constructor snippet:

```
StartGui() {
    /*
     * Display everything in GUI to user
     */
    int mainWindowSizeWidth = 800;
    int mainWindowSizeHeight = 600;

    setContentPane(backgroundFrame);
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(guiImgIconLocName)));
    setTitle("Final Fantasy 7 Level Up Calculator");
    add(topFrameScroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(centerFrameScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    setSize(mainWindowSizeWidth,mainWindowSizeHeight);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

When creating the artifacts, I'm guessing there is a step to include the images (I'm not an expert and this is my first swing project)...
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like the image isn't in the JAR or isn't in the CLASSPATH.  Can you open the JAR and see it?  Is it in the manifest?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by manifest (guessing the src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF) This only has two lines `Manifest-Version: 1.0` and `Main-Class: Main.StartGui`. I'm not sure if the JAR file can see it or not. I've zipped up the entire project so you can see for yourself - https://www.dropbox.com/s/oavmfzj2apavcvc/FF7LevelUpStatCalculator.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm not downloading anything.  This is up to you, not me.

Comment: `guiImgIconLocName = "/images/TitleBarIcon.png"`

Comment: okay, well the issue is I can't see if the JAR file can see the images or not, because it's a file that has code already compiled. All I can say is the program runs fine when I run it with my compiler.

Comment: @Crazy Coder I've tried that too, I get the same error. I read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749668/exporting-images-with-my-jar-file) to change it to `\\\`, but still the same error.

Comment: `Main/StartGui.java:106`, change to `private final String imgDir = "/images/";` Rebuild the jar. Worked for me: http://i.imgur.com/2QRSrbH.png.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch Crazy Coder. I guess it didn't like `..` in the path. If you put this in an answer, I can give you credit for it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should reference the resources starting from the root of the jar (`/`) and using the forward slashes.

In `Main/StartGui.java:106`, change to

```
private final String imgDir = "/images/";
```

Rebuild the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your images in resources. Create resources folder in the project root. Right click on resources folder and  "Mark directory as -> Resources root". And then create jar.